# How put a string for result of ternary operator in angular

Tags: angular, ternary-operator

I fetch datas from a REST API on my Angular app, and try to put text in some text fields.
I tried to use ternary-operator to test if my data exist so I do

```
    <input matInput matTooltip="{{index.tooltip}}" pattern="{{index.restriction}}" name="{{index.name}}" 
[(ngModel)]="detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(index.name) ? detailsArray[index.name] : ''" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

If I don't use the attribute [ngModelOption], there is an error to

but it give me an error, anyone have an idea of Why do the string '' not work ? Is my code wrong ?

My error :

```
[ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(index.name) ? detailsArray[index.name] : ''" [ngModelOptions"): ng:///AppModule/DetailsComponent.html@18:108
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 72 in [detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(index.name) ? detailsArray[index.name] : ''=$event] in ng:///AppModule/DetailsComponent.html@18:108
```

Comment: Your `ngModel` syntax is good, seems like the issue is the next attribute. Could you show the entire tag ?

Comment: [ngModel] OK, [(ngModel)] WRONG, you can not change something else a variable, by the way, why not use {{detailsArray.hasOwnProperty(index.name) ? detailsArray[index.name] : ''}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eliseo said in comment, your code is fine for `[ngModel]`, but not for `[(ngModel)]`. `[(ngModel)]` is just shortcut for this:
`<input [ngModel]="valueToModel" (ngModelChange)="valueToModel = $event" >`. See more at [guide](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview), where difference between statement and expression is shown.

Comment: Thanks to you and @Eliseo, you solve my problem, honestly I feel stupid haha ^^'